# How to wait on a task which does not return anything but does manipulate data that needs to be used?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library, multitasking

I am running synchronous code. However I need to call a task from a third party library I consume (and hence no control over it), and wait for it to be completed. The task does not have return value but it does update an object passed in as a parameter.

SerializaAsync is defined as

```
public async Task SerializeAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I need to read the memory stream after the task completes. However since the task does not return a Task<T> the GetAwaiter.GetResult() is not valid.

So what I cannot do is something like

```
var result = resusmbResponseSerializer.SerializeAsync(
    typeof(CustomHttpResponse),
    smbDeliveryResponse,
    memoryStream, // pass a new MemoryStream() and task will update the stream with content
    CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

So I tried to do this.

```
string responseJson = null;
smbResponseSerializer.SerializeAsync(
    typeof(CusometHttpResponse),
    smbDeliveryResponse,
    memoryStream, // pass a new MemoryStream() and task will update the stream with content
    CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() =>
    {
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
        {
            responseJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    });

string readValue = responseJson; // this gets executed before the OnCompletedAction completes.
```

This does not work because the task may not have completed and onCompleted is not yet called. Hence readValue is null (responseJson value at that time).

I could wait for the task using task.wait but then I want to avoid the aggregateexception

is there a better way to wait for this task to be completed and memory stream can be read synchronously?

Comment: what is wrong with `await resusmbResponseSerializer.SerializeAsync(...)`

Comment: Hi you said the method is defined as "public async Task SerializeAsync", but later "the task does not return a Task". Pretty strange. For me it seems await or GetAwaiter().GetResult() are the obvious choice.

Comment: *"I need to [...] wait for it to be completed."* <=== when you say *wait* you mean synchronously? In other words are you OK with blocking the current thread while waiting for the task to complete?

Comment: @Mono it was encoding issue, fixed.It basically does not return task with a return value T

Comment: Can you modify your current code to be async instead of synchronous? Why not?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes. I want to block the current thread as I am dependent on the outcome of the result and I dont have any other parallel work to do.

Comment: Still no reason to block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` with non-generic `Task`s, in which case the [`GetResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult) method returns `void`. So you just need to remove the `var result =` from your statement:

```
resusmbResponseSerializer.SerializeAsync(typeof(CustomHttpResponse),
    smbDeliveryResponse, memoryStream, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
// At this point the memoryStream has been updated
```

Admittedly a method named `GetResult` that returns `void` is unconventional. Probably is was named this way for consistency with the generic `Task<TResult>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to await a `Task` synchronously then I would suggest the following extension method for that:

```
public static class AsyncHelper
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory TaskFactory = 
        new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static void RunSync(this Func<Task> func)
        => TaskFactory
            .StartNew(func).Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

The usage would look like this:

```
var serializeAsync = async () => 
     await resusmbResponseSerializer.SerializeAsync(
             typeof(CustomHttpResponse),
             smbDeliveryResponse,
             memoryStream,
             CancellationToken.None);

serializeAsync().RunSync();
//Process memorystream
```

Comment: this would still mean I have to make the function to return a async Task. I wanted my code to not return tasks and remain synchronous.

Comment: @Akrajak No, that's not true. Your calling method entirely sync. You create an asynchronous delegate and then you "span a new thread" to execute your delegate and you wait for it to finish. Yes you use more than 1 threads to execute but it still sync.